# Left join sql issue in PHP

Tags: php, sql, left-join

Im having an issue with an sql statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cust LEFT JOIN survey AS survey ON
cust.cid=survey.cust_id WHERE cust.clinic='1' LIMIT $start, $limit";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo row['id'];
}
```

cust is the table of all customers, survey is the table of all the
surveys they take..

This statement should only show rows from the cust db and include info from the survey table, but for some reason, it will show each customer in the cust table as many times as surveys they have taken.
So if customer 1 from the cust table has 3 surveys in the survey table, this statmente will display that customer 3 times.. How can I change the statement to still have the info from
the survey table but only show each cust once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite see what you are trying to do with that query. But it really looks like you're missing a `GROUP BY cust.cid` before the `LIMIT`.